# activex component not clickable in labview

Tags: activex, labview

i have made a very simple labview VI which has an activeX component in it. I can insert an ActiveX container, and I can right-click on that container to get a microsoft toolbar 6.0. However, when I then click (left or right) in block diagram mode on that control, no menu appear, no properties, nothing.

It works fine on my collegue's computer so i'm tempted to think its a component I dont have installed on my computer.

There are a few suspicious differences from both machines, mostly IVI componentsbut I have downloaded and installed those as well.

Anybody encountered the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, well, i've found the way to correct this. Just reset labview to original factory specs.
i.e. delete the labview.ini file, or rename it... labview will run from defaults.